# Is there a Spanish to English dictionary for use with python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk, python-3.4

I am trying to create my own digital Spanish to English database by translating the entire Spanish corpus found in nltk 3.0 for python 3. I am using the Google tool-kit to do the translating and its proving to be a very slow process.  i am wondering if there exists a Spanish to English dictionary(preferably in module form) that i can import and use in python 3. Below is the code i have to do the translating manually. So far it's taking around 12.5 minutes per 5000 translations.

```
import goslate
import nltk
import pickle
x = pickle.load(open( "espcorpus.pickle", "rb" ))
gs = goslate.Goslate()
y = len(x)
y = y-1
print(y)
z = 0
b = []
n = 0
error = 0
import pickle
while z < 192683:
    n = n + 1
    while -1 < z < (4481*n):
        try:
            c = gs.translate(x[z], 'en', 'es')
            word=nltk.word_tokenize(c)
            c = nltk.pos_tag(word)
            b.append(c[0])
            print(z)
            z += 1
        except:
            continue
            error += 1
    pickle.dump(b, (open('filename%s.pickle' % n, 'wb')))
    print(n)
    b = []
    print('errors: %i' % error)
idealist = []
n = 1
while n<27:
    print(n)
    target = 'filename%s.pickle' % n
    with open(target, "rb") as file:
        unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(file)
        poop = unpickler.load()
        x = len(poop)
        z = 0
        while z<x:
            idealist.append(poop[z])
            z= z +1
    n = n + 1
    print(len(idealist))
    pickle.dump(idealist, (open('master.pickle', 'wb')))
```

How i would want to have the final database setup:
[Spanish word, English word, English Part of Speech tag]

Please let me know if I left anything out.

Thank you ahead of time for your expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any dictionary specially formatted for python, just a format you can digest with python, and that would mean pretty much any well known text format. Just try to find an opensource dictionary in an easy to digest format and parse it with python.

Here for example: http://www.dicts.info/uddl.php